# What to do when the close voters don't comment?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

My question [Can I use a foot pedal to send mouse clicks and/or modifier keys ergonomically?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/25/43) got put on hold as "too broad". I modified the question to refine the scope, cast a reopen vote, but the question is still on hold and no close voter left any comment since then. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Not much. Closing doesn't require a comment, and I personally don't leave one, although I try to for down votes.

You know *why* they closed because it says (too broad), so it isn't really needed. I'd also object to comments asking me to reopen something I've closed, just like I don't like haranging over my down vote.

Anyway, I've voted to reopen, so only 1 more is needed. Any other time, I'd discourage this question - it will go into the reopen queue and be dealt with - but here there are so few (13 perhaps?) people reviewing, I can see why you did this.

---

I just saw the comments you posted. I would be quite frustrated at that. For future reference, to have more than one `@user` insert the `` ` `` (backtick) character and you can do as many users as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the issue is that the point of putting a question on hold is to allow the OP to improve the question... but then if nobody gives feedback on the OP's edits, then putting a question on hold doesn't really make sense (we could just close it right away).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/178179: _If a question has been closed, then for the first 5 days, it is marked as “on hold” rather than “closed”. This is meant to convey that the question requires improvement and may be reopened if improved. During this period, if the question is edited by the asker (now by anyone), it will be added to the reopen queue. Other than this, there is no functional difference between “on hold” and “closed”._

Comment: my understanding is that on hold = we give an opportunity to the OP to improve the question ; closed = ask somewhere else.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, got it. Thanks for the backtick trick to add more than one user!

Comment: "...just like I don't like haranging over my down vote." So well expressed.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thanks :) I'm happy to comment if I think I should, but by no means do I want to be "attacked" for a courtesy. It makes me want to not comment sometimes...

Comment: @Tim - I feel exactly the same way. I think I'm going to post about it.